# Retrieve an app configuration setting in a non-request context in Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid

In a pyramid app I am building (called pyplay), I need to retrieve an application setting that I have in development.ini. The problem is that the place where I am trying to get that setting cannot access the request variable (e.g. at the top level of a module file).

So, after looking at this example in the documentation: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/configuration/django_settings.html I started doing something very simple and hardcoded at first just to make it work.
Since my development.ini has this section: [app:main], then the simple example I tried is as follows:

```
from paste.deploy.loadwsgi import appconfig
config = appconfig('config:development.ini', 'main', relative_to='.')
```

but the application refuses to start and displays the following error:

```
ImportError: <module 'pyplay' from '/home/pish/projects/pyplay/__init__.pyc'> has no 'main' attribute
```

So, thinking that maybe I should put 'pyplay' instead of 'main', I went ahead, but I get this error instead:

```
LookupError: No section 'pyplay' (prefixed by 'app' or 'application' or 'composite' or 'composit' or 'pipeline' or 'filter-app') found in config ./development.ini
```

At this point I am a bit stuck and I don't know what am I doing wrong. Can someone please give me a hand on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** The following are the contents of my development.ini file (note that pish.theparam is the setting I am trying to get):

```
###
# app configuration
# http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/environment.html
###

[app:main]
use = egg:pyplay

pyramid.reload_templates = true
pyramid.debug_authorization = false
pyramid.debug_notfound = false
pyramid.debug_routematch = false
pyramid.default_locale_name = en_US.utf8
pyramid.includes =
    pyramid_debugtoolbar
    pyramid_tm

sqlalchemy.url = mysql://user:passwd@localhost/pyplay?charset=utf8

# By default, the toolbar only appears for clients from IP addresses
# '127.0.0.1' and '::1'.
debugtoolbar.hosts = 127.0.0.1 ::1

pish.theparam = somevalue

###
# wsgi server configuration
###

[server:main]
use = egg:waitress#main
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 6543

###
# logging configuration
# http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/logging.html
###

[loggers]
keys = root, pyplay, sqlalchemy

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = INFO
handlers = console

[logger_pyplay]
level = DEBUG
handlers =
qualname = pyplay

[logger_sqlalchemy]
level = INFO
handlers =
qualname = sqlalchemy.engine
# "level = INFO" logs SQL queries.
# "level = DEBUG" logs SQL queries and results.
# "level = WARN" logs neither.  (Recommended for production systems.)

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s][%(threadName)s] %(message)s
```

Comment: What does your development.ini file look like?

Comment: @Peter, I just edited the question and added the contents of my development.ini file. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The reason it's difficult to do in pyramid is because it's *always* a bad idea to have module-level settings. It means your module can only ever be used in one way per-process (different code-paths can't use your library in different ways). :-)

A hack around not having access to the request object is to at least hide your global behind a function call, so that the global can be different per-thread (which is basically per-request).

```
def get_my_param(registry=None):
    if registry is None:
        registry = pyramid.threadlocals.get_current_registry()
    return registry.settings['pyplay.theparam']
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation Michael. One of the things I was thinking is that if this setting I am trying to get will be used to set the `__table_args__` of some sqlalchemy models, then calling this function from the top level scope of the .py that has the definitions of these models may return nothing for registry.settings right? While playing with this, I see that changing the `__table_args__` of a sqlalchemy model at 'runtime' has no effect in the query calls (like if it was ignoring the change).

Comment: Yeah SQLAlchemy makes model configuration difficult, unfortunately. Module-level settings also depend on things like importing the module after the settings and fun stuff like that. For something like SQLAlchemy I would probably take the `DBSession` approach, which is to set it in some `meta` module that all the other modules import, and be sure not to import those other modules first.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: create a singleton class say in a file xyz_file

```
class Singleton:
def __init__(self, klass):
    self.klass = klass
    self.instance = None
def __call__(self, *args, **kwds):
    if self.instance == None:
        self.instance = self.klass(*args, **kwds)
    return self.instance

@Singleton
class ApplicationSettings(object):
   def __init__(self, app_settings=None):
       if app_settings is not None :
           self._settings = app_settings
   def get_appsettings_object(self):
       return self

   def get_application_configuration(self):
       return self._settings
```

Step 2: in  "__ init__.py"

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
  ....
  .......
  app_settings = ApplicationSettings(settings)
```

Step 3: You should be able to access in any part of the code.

```
  from xyz_file import ApplicationSettings
  app_settings = ApplicationSettings().get_application_configuration()
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you don't have access to the request object, you're "off the rails" in Pyramid. To do things the Pyramid way, we make components and figure out where they belong in the Pyramid lifecycle, and they should always have direct access to either or both of the registry (the ZCA) and the request.

If what you're doing doesn't fit in the the request lifecycle, then it's probably something that should be instantiated at server start up time, normally in your **init**.py where you build and fill the configurator (our access to the registry). Don't be afraid to use the registry to allow other components to get at things 'pseudo-globally' later. So probably you want to make some kind of factory for your thing, call the factory in your start up code, perhaps passing in a reference to the registry as an argument, and then attach the object to the registry. If your component needs to interface with request-lifecycle code, give it a method that takes request as a param. Later anything that needs at this object can get it from registry, and anything this object needs to get at can be done either through registry or request.

You can totally use the hack in the other answer to get at the current global registry, but needing to do so is a code smell, you can def figure out a better design to eliminate that.

pseudo code example, in the server start up code:

```
# in in the init block where our Configurator has been built
from myfactory import MyFactory
registry.my_component = MyFactory(config.registry)
# you can now get at my_component from anywhere in a pyramid system
```

your component:

```
class MyFactory(oject):
    def __init__(self, registry):
        # server start up lifecycle stuff here    
        self.registry = registry

    def get_something(self, request):
        # do stuff with the rest of the system
        setting_wanted = self.registry.settings['my_setting']
```

Pyramid Views work this way. They are actually ZCA multi-adapters of request and context. Their *factory* is registered in the registry, and then when the view look up process kicks off, the factory instantiates a view passing in request as a param.